# Finished activity is reopened after clicking back button at the next activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activities A, B and C. Activity A is launcher activity. It opens activity B via startActivityForResult. When activity B is ready to provide the result, it calls `setResult()` and `finish()` methods. After this, activity A opens activity C (via `startActivity()`) and finishes itself. But when the user clicks system back button at activity C, activity B is recreated. But the expected result is that activity C is destroyed and application goes to background. How can I fix this behavior? Thanks in advance for any help! Here are some code snippets:

Fragment inside activity A:

```
private val aResult = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) {
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            openC()
        }
    }

    private fun showB() {
        Intent(requireContext(), B::class.java).apply {
            aResult.launch(this)
            activity?.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
        }
    }
```

Fragment inside activity B:

```
private fun navigateBack(resultCode: Int? = null) {
    resultCode?.let { activity?.setResult(it) }
    activity?.finish()
}
```

Fragment inside activity A:

```
private fun openC() {
    startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), C::class.java))
    activity?.finish()
}
```

Activity C:

```
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, enabled = true) {
        if (navController.currentDestination?.id in appBarConfiguration.topLevelDestinations) {
            finish()
        } else {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
    }
```

Lifecycle logs:

```
A *onCreate
A *onCreate
A *onResume
A *onPause
B *onCreate
B *onStart
B *onResume
A *onStop
B *onPause
A *onStart
C *onCreate
C *onStart
C *onResume
B *onStop
B *onDestroy
A *onStop
A *onDestroy
```

click back at C:

```
C *onPause
B *onCreate
B *onStart
B *onResume
C *onStop
C *onDestroy
```

Comment: Can you add 
android:noHistory="true" 
tag to activity B in AndroidManifest.xml file and try?

Answer (score -2):

The behavior you're describing is expected when activity B was started using `startActivityForResult` from activity A. When activity B finishes and returns a result to activity A, it goes through the `onCreate`, `onStart`, and `onResume` lifecycle methods again when you click back from activity C. This is because activity A is still waiting for the result from activity B, so it needs to be in the resumed state to receive the result.

If you don't want activity B to be recreated when you click back from activity C, you have a few options:

1. Don't finish activity A when you open activity C. Keep activity A running in the background so that it can receive the result from activity B when it finishes. This way, activity A will remain in the resumed state, and activity B won't be recreated when you click back from activity C.

```kotlin
// Inside activity A
private fun openC() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, C::class.java))
    // Don't call finish() here
}
```

2. If you want to finish activity A when you open activity C, then you can modify the flow to use a different mechanism to open activity C. For example, you can use a new task or a different intent flag to launch activity C. This way, activity A won't be waiting for a result from activity B.

```kotlin
// Inside activity A, when opening activity C
val intent = Intent(this, C::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

By using one of these approaches, you can control whether activity B gets recreated when you navigate back from activity C.